# How to receive Unsigned int value for a net-snmp variable

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have a AgentX sub-agent working with net-snmp master agent. I want to convert an unsigned int value to the snmp type and print it using the snmpget command. I have used the following function:

```
snmp_set_var_typed_value(var,
                         ASN_UNSIGNED,
                         (u_char *)&runnableEntry_tbl[major-1].runnableObjectCounters.counters[counter_index-1].value,
                         sizeof(unsigned int));
```

(where `runnableEntry_tbl[major-1].runnableObjectCounters.counters[counter_index-1].value` is an unsigned value).

The problem is the value is getting transmitted as a Gauge32 (as per wireshark), also the display of the value with snmpget is something like:

```
runnableObjectCounters.1.1 = Gauge32: 4294967294
```

Can the Gauge32 be removed somehow? Or is there some other type for Unsigned32 as per ASN, please help me.

I am working on Linux.

Comment: From what i have found out the asn type to be used is ASN_UNSIGNED and the receiving MIB variable is Unsigned32. I have used these , still i am getting the value as Gauge32

Answer (score 1):

According to the RFCs ([1902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1902) and [2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578)) Gauge32 and Unsigned32 are interchangeable.  A relevant section from the [RFC 2578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578):

```
-- this doesn't wrap
Gauge32 ::=
    [APPLICATION 2]
        IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)

-- an unsigned 32-bit quantity
-- indistinguishable from Gauge32
Unsigned32 ::=
    [APPLICATION 2]
        IMPLICIT INTEGER (0..4294967295)
```

As far as the standard is concerned, an Unsigned32 and a Gauge32 will be indistinguishable from one another on the wire.

See [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756666/what-is-the-correct-encoding-for-snmp-type-unsigned32) for a little more discussion about Unsigned32 and Gauge32 within the SNMP specification.

If you're trying to get `snmpget` to display the expected type, you may  have some luck if you make sure the MIB for your sub-agent is loaded in the path.  Several ways to accomplish this are described on the Net-SNMP wiki page, [Using and Loading MIBS](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS).

One of the easier ways is to put the MIB in one of the directories that get loaded by Net-SNMP, `$HOME/.snmp/mibs` or `/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs` (this directory varies by linux distribution, you can call `net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs` to get a list of directories searched by Net-SNMP).

Once your MIB is in the correct location, you should be able to call `snmpget` with the `-m` option,

```
snmpget -m +YOUR-SPECIFIC-MIB <other-snmp-options>
```

where `YOUR-SPECIFIC-MIB` is replaced with the name of the MIB you care about.

Comment: Thanks lostriebo for that information. i am using the mib in the snmpget command and my OIDs are getting mapped properly as per the mib as mentioned below:

runnableObjectCounters.1.1 = Gauge32: 4294967294 

This item has been defined as Unsigned32 and is getting mapped properly via the MIB. MY concern now is that is there any way i can remove the Gauge32: prefix present before the value? Or i can get something like "Unsigned32:" prefixed before the value so that i can confidently say that yes the value is "Unsigned32" and not Gauge32, even though both are same. :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across things like ASN_UINTEGER, but i guess it is outdated. As per the mentioned post, ASN_UNSIGNED32 is not supported in UNIX. So we are left with ASN_UNSIGNED only. But again the display is confusing even though Gauge32 and Unsigned32 is same :)